# Download Files from Url using React

Tags: reactjs

I have this link https://carbon-copies-restapi.herokuapp.com/all-order-histories.txt which contains some data. I want to download it as a file using React. I tried many solutions from StackOverflow but nothing worked for me.
One of the solutions I found on the internet that did not work either.

```
const downloadFile = async () => {
    fetch(
      "https://carbon-copies-restapi.herokuapp.com/all-order-histories.txt"
    ).then((response) => {
      response.blob().then((blob) => {
        let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        let a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = url;
        a.download = "orders.txt";
        a.click();
      });
      //window.location.href = response.url;
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout [Filesaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) for downloading Small Files and for Big file and more control use [StramSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js)

Using `FileSaver JS`

```
FileSaver.saveAs("https://carbon-copies-restapi.herokuapp.com/all-order-histories.txt", "histories.txt");
```

---

Other Methods using `FileSaver JS`

```
const downloadFile = async () => {
fetch("https://carbon-copies-restapi.herokuapp.com/all-order-histories.txt").then((response) => {
  response.blob().then((blob) => {
    var FileSaver = require('file-saver');
    var blob = new Blob(blob, {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, "hello world.txt");
  });
});
```

Comment: Can we download the images as well using this package?

Comment: Yes check you can Check out their [Documentation](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)

Comment: `FileSaver.saveAs( "https://carbon-copiesrestapi.herokuapp.com/image_1628053278730.jpg",
      "histories.jpg");`
It opened image in new tab rather than downloading.

Comment: read there docs carefully and see what they are saying

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by myself. This is how I resolved it.

1. Installed package **react-file-download**.
2. Imported it `var fileDownload = require("react-file-download");`
3. I was getting all the data from backend in this object *allOrders.data.rentalHistories*. Stringify it and stored it in file name allOrders.txt and invoked the function on button click. But this approach is only useful if you are getting this data from backend
   `const downloadFile = () => { fileDownload( JSON.stringify(allOrders.data.rentalHistories), "allOrders.txt" ); };`

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function - https://imgur.com/d4GEGYo
you could show all code?